# org.openqa.selenium.SesionNotCreatedException: Couldnt start a new sesion.Posible causes are invalid adres of remote server or browser startup failur

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

```
[ERROR] Tests run: 24, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 23, Time elapsed: 2.458 s <<< FAILURE! -- in TestSuite
[ERROR] org.testpackage.TC001_Signup.launch[org.testng.TestRunner@2cf92cc7, chrome](0) -- Time elapsed: 1.670 s <<< FAILURE!
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: 
Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure
```

.